# display the other page results in the required page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, iframe

I have a form that posts data to a url which is a other domain.. I have to use the form in my domain with out changing the url in the address bar...
details...

I have a search box(which posts the data to a url http://otherdomain.com/search) in the http://mydoamin.com/index.html
now when I click on submit it shows the results in the otherdomain...

I need to make a page http://mydoamin.com/search.html and display the results here..

How can I do this.. (using iframes, javascript, jquery or php)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like your wanting to take the search results from the otherdomain.com and show the results on your site instead of redirecting the user to the otherdomain.com. Is that about right?

If so what you want to look into is screen scraping via PHP, there are a couple of techniques (Curl & regex) that can be used, here is an extremely simple example I just made up using google as an example.

Create a file called search.php and put this code into it - should work straight off the bat.

```
<h1> Super Search Site </h1>

<form action="search.php" method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="search" />
        <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

 @$searchString = $_REQUEST["search"];

if(isset($searchString))
{
$pageRaw = file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=$searchString");
$newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B"); //removes all white space - inclding tabs, newlines etc - makes easier when using regex
$pageCleaned = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($pageRaw));

/*
 * $contentStart = the start of content wanted
 * $contentEnd = the end of content wanted
 * $contentWanted  = content between $contentStart and $contentWanted
 */

$contentStart = strpos($pageCleaned,'<ol>'); //Looks in the source code for <ol>
$contentEnd = strpos($pageCleaned,'</ol>',$contentStart); //Looks in the source code for </ol>
$contentWanted = substr($pageCleaned,$contentStart,$contentEnd-$contentStart);

echo $contentWanted;
}
else
{ return; }

?>
```

Comment: i want the exact thing like this but, the search engine takes only post elements.. i.e, it wont take a query string :) its my mistake i haven't mentioned it in the question... any ways this was great and very thankful to you i will use this technique in my other projects

Comment: This link should help you out :) [Sending HTTP POST via Curl](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl)